# Ruby Backticks - break command into multiple lines?

Tags: ruby, shell, backticks

In Ruby, I know I can execute a shell command with backticks like so:

```
`ls -l | grep drw-`
```

However, I'm working on a script which calls for a few fairly long shell commands, and for readability's sake I'd like to be able to break it out onto multiple lines. I'm assuming I can't just throw in a plus sign as with Strings, but I'm curious if there is either a command concatenation technique of some other way to cleanly break a long command string into multiple lines of source code.

Comment: Personally, if I need to call some long shell commands, I'd put them into a shell script, and then call that and capture its output. I'd rather maintain shell scripts separately from my Ruby code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use interpolation:

```
`#{"ls -l" +
   "| grep drw-"}`
```

or put the command into a variable and interpolate the variable:

```
cmd = "ls -l" +
      "| grep drw-"
`#{cmd}`
```

Depending on your needs, you may also be able to use a [different method of running the shell command](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html), such as [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system), but note its behavior is not exactly the same as backticks.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be something simple but I had trouble forming my google query to get something meaningful back.

Answer (score 55):

You can escape carriage returns with a `\`:

```
`ls -l \
 | grep drw-`
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `%x`:

```
%x( ls -l |
    grep drw- )
```

Another:

```
%x(
  echo a
  echo b
  echo c
)
# => "a\nb\nc\n"
```

Comment: Note that it's crucial to have pipes (`|`) at the end of the first line, not at the beginning of the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with explicit `\n`:

```
cmd_str = "ls -l\n" +
          "| grep drw-"
```

...and then put the combined string inside backticks.

```
`#{cmd_str}`
```